# How can I insert a new top level TODO below the current subtree in org-mode without moving the cursor?

Tags: org-mode

To insert a new TODO in org-mode, I currently move my cursor to the end of the current line and use the `M-S-<RET>` shortcut. If I am within a subtree, I also have to go to the end of the last tree item.

I was wondering if it is possible to create a shortcut which appends a new top-level TODO (i.e., a single *) below whatever subtree the cursor is in. Eliminating the cursor movements would be very helpful to me while brainstorming and quickly capturing thoughts.

Comment: Do you always want to insert a top level heading? It seems like that might break your hierarchy if you were more than two levels down.  If not, `outline-up-heading` followed by `org-insert-heading-after-current` will work.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about `org-insert-heading-after-current`. Yes, that combined with `outline-up-heading` is probably the better route to go.

`org-insert-heading-after-current` solves my needs a little better as it skips over sublevels within a tree as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function adds a new headline after the parent of the headline the cursor is on.  With a prefix argument, it adds the heading `arg` levels up.

```
(defun org-insert-heading-after-parent (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (save-excursion
    (outline-up-heading arg)
    (org-insert-heading-after-current)
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional function, but in practice, I think I will likely just go with your original suggestion of using the 2 commands separately.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple function to do something similar.

```
(defun test ()
  (point-to-register 'p)
  (search-forward-regexp "^\\* ")
  (org-beginning-of-line)
  (insert "*
")
  (register-to-point 'p))
```

Comment: Thanks. That function takes care of the cursor issue, but it seems to add a new item at the same tree level as wherever the cursor is, rather than at the top level. 

That is certainly useful, but is it possible to instead insert a new top-level item after the current tree?

This is close enough though, and I may actually end up using this function instead.

Comment: Should be simple to change, I wasn't entirely sure where you wanted it inserted.  Just change outline-next-visible-heading to a command that moves beyond the current tree.

Comment: It looks like there isn't quite that command, but org-mode is conveniently plain text, so `(search-forward-regexp "^\\* ")` seems to do the trick.

Comment: @user2699 You might find `save-excursion` a easier to use way to save the point since it also saves the mark and the state of the region.  Also, your `progn` seems unnecessary.

Comment: @erikstokes thanks, I didn't realize that.